# Get sensor details for Emotiv Epoc +

Tags: emokit

I would like to get a raw eeg for Epoc+ helment

Calls to method

`engine.HeadsetGetSensorDetails(EdkDll.IEE_InputChannels_t.IEE_CHAN_AF3);`

from C# wrapper of community sdk, lead to exception in unmanaged code (edk.dll)

Does anyone access raw eeg from the headset? How do you do it? I'd like any solution, not only for .net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The community sdk will not give you the raw data. There is an open source solution called emokit (https://github.com/openyou/emokit) that you can use. It takes a bit of effort to set up, but this may be the solution for you. An example using this project can be found here (https://github.com/YosephT/Neurofeedback-Meditation)

Comment: Doesn't the word "Plus" in Epoc Plus mean access to raw data? Why does community sdk have `public EdkDll.IInputSensorDescriptor_t HeadsetGetSensorDetails(EdkDll.IEE_InputChannels_t channelId)`?

Comment: I believe the 'Plus' refers to it having more sensors than the deprecated Epoc. I do not know why that method is there, but if you check the emotiv website here (https://www.emotiv.com/developer/) you can see that raw data only comes with the Premium edition

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider porting [emokit-java](https://github.com/fommil/emokit-java/tree/master/src/main/java/com/github/fommil/emokit) to c# if you want to avoid python completely.